# Reading and Writing to a Text File within the Release Folder of a C# Console App

Tags: c#

I have a C# console application that uses text from a txt file as a parameter for a SQL query. After the query runs, it stores the highest primary key in the text file. The next time it runs, it uses the first line of that text file in the WHERE statement to grab primary keys higher than the previously stored one. Here's the code I'm using:

// get latest primary key

```
static String mostRecentID= File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\DataStorage\latestID.txt").First().Trim();
```

// run the query

```
SELECT * FROM whatever WHERE pk > mostRecentID
```

// store latest primary key

```
DataRow mostRecentIDRow= exportTable.Select().FirstOrDefault();
        if (mostRecentIDRow!= null)
        {
            mostRecentID = mostRecentIDRow[0].ToString().Trim();
            File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\DataStorage\latestID.txt", new String[] { mostRecentID});
        }
```

I need to be able to read and write to this text file independent of where the program or the file is located. Is there a way to do this while keeping it in the release folder of the program?

Comment: why don't you ask the user for the file as a commandline argument?

Comment: You want to read/write the file in the applications root directory?

Comment: Keep the file in the application root.

Comment: In windows, `Registry` is a good place to contain complete data or a path to configuration file. Yet something has to be known (file location or registry key), asked (from user/server/software local configuration) or found (you could theoretically find your file). Idea of @DanielA.White, probably the best, provide a parameter to specify path. Value can then be *locally* stored and reused to find file again if parameter is missing. Or you can try to search in known places (to example, next to exe-file). Not found - throw error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use this variable:

```
 string myDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

to get the directory where you program executes.

So when you place your .txt in Release Folder you can use:

```
 File.WriteAllLines(myDirectory + "/" + "latestID.txt", new String[] { mostRecentID});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to keep the text file in the root location of the application use this

```
string file = Path.Combine(
     System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, "latestID.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the path of the current running assembly like this:

```
 string path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );
```

and there you can save/load your file